# Validate whether a QR code has already been scanned ASP.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, validation

I have created a QR code generator in ASP.net. Now every time I scan a generated QR code, i need to verify whether that QR code has already been scanned. I have to do this by checking in database (SQL) against the BIT of that particular code. once the QR code gets scanned, the bit should update itself  as 1 or else remains 0. So next time while scanning the same QR code it should give me a message stating that the QR code has already been scanned if the bit against that QR code is 1. pls help

Comment: What have you tried so far to do accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You not need to set a bit for checking that QR code already scanned, You have to make a separate table where you can save deviceids and that QR ids which you are try to scan, Once a user scan that QR Code add an entry in that table, so next time when he scan from same deviceid it will not allow him/her to scan.